# How to find out if the Sympy variable is complex?

Tags: python, sympy, complex-numbers

I am writing a code which involves solving this equation

```
X = solve(Theta_Mod_Eqn*Ramp_Equation/(x+PT) - C, x)
```

I am using sympy library, now the equation has 7 roots few are complex and few are real. I am unable to segregate them because `isinstance(i,complex)` is always returning true

```
for i in X:
    if not isinstance(i,complex):
        if (i>-0.01 and i<maxSheaveDisp):
            A = i;
```

for one case 
    i = -0.000581431210287302 - 0.2540334478167*I

```
In:i == complex
Out[39]: False
```

How to find out if the variable is complex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of real numbers is a subset of the set of complex numbers. So, every real number is a complex number. For example, 3 is a complex number.

The correct question to ask is how to find out if a root is real. For that, you can use `i.is_real` if i is a SymPy symbol:

```
for i in X:
    if i.is_real:
        if (i>-0.01 and i<maxSheaveDisp):
            A = i
```

One can also compare `im(i) to 0`: if `im(i) == 0`. This works for Python floats too.